# how to display images in php from database using MYSQLi queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below is the code from where my page jumps to the "prac_image_display" to display images:-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("database.php");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from mst_subject");
    echo "<h2><table cellpadding=5>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><img height='50' width='50' src='prac_img_display.php? id=".$row['sub_id']."'></td><td><a href=showtest.php?subid={$row['sub_id']}>".$row['sub_name']."</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        //$_SESSION['subid']=$row['sub_id'];
    }
    echo "</table></h2>";
?>
```

And now below is the code written in prac_image_display.php file:-

```
        <?php

       if(isset($_GET['id']))
       {
        include("database.php");
        $sql = "SELECT image FROM mst_subject WHERE 
       sub_id=".$_GET['id'].";";
       //$sql = "SELECT image FROM mst_subject WHERE sub_id=8";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,"$sql");
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        echo mysqli_result($result,0);
        mysqli_close($con);
     }
     else 
     {
           echo 'Please use a real id number';
     }
    ?>
```

Below is the code written in "database.php" file :-

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die("could not 
                         connect ");
    //mysql_select_db("test",$con)  or die("Could connect to Database");
    ?>
```

The images are stored in the database in BLOB.
The problem is when I use MYSQL in both .php files as shown above it runs fine and all the images get displayed on localhost perfectly but when I replace MYSQL functions with MYSQLi functions the images do not get displayed. please, tell me what changes can I do here.

Comment: point of note. In your while loop, that <tr> on the third line of your code within the loop should be </tr>

Comment: what you have in `database.php`? untill we see that,we can't tell what problem you are getting

Comment: show your database.php too

Comment: A side note: your database query is wide open to sql injection attacks. Please learn about the security benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Comment: Did you check connection error for mysqli? you can't blindly replace all mysql_ functions with mysqli_

Comment: Only a guess, can you try using `echo mysqli_result($result,0,0);` to output the first field rather than the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps to `DEBUG` and find out where is the actual problem.

> **Step 1 :** Update your Image `src`

```
src='prac_img_display.php? id=".$row['sub_id']."'
/*TO*/
src='prac_img_display.php?id=".$row['sub_id']."'
```

**Note :** Because, there is a `Blank space`.

> **Step 2 :** Browse your Image `URL` in Browser, like

```
example.com/prac_img_display.php?id=8
```

**Note :** Check, If the image Display properly In your browser window.

**IF, Not displaying Image properly**

> **Step 3 :** Check `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` is correct.

Suppose, If you uploaded `PNG` image, This will not work.

For `PNG` image you should use `header("Content-type: image/png");`

**Note :** Also don't forget to `DEBUG` **SQL** Result.